# A question about Jacob Fox's graph removal lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, extremal-graph-theory

I have a question about the paper "A new proof of the graph removal lemma" by Jacob Fox.
I will preface this by saying I've looked around in papers citing this paper and couldn't find an answer to my question.

For some context : A graph removal lemma states that if a graph contains at most $o(n^k)$ copies of some graph on $k$ vertices, we only need to remove $o(n^2)$ edges from the graph in order to eliminate all copies. All proofs I am familiar with of the removal lemma are constructive - meaning they indicate the specific set of edges that need to be removed, and so they induce an algorithm which finds these edges by the criterion the proof specifies. Standard proofs of the removal lemma use a regularity lemma, and so the specific bound on the number of edges which need to be removed is a derivative of the dependencies of the regularity lemma used (and those include a tower type dependency, nothing better is known for regularity lemmas). Jacob Fox was able to achieve a better bound on the number of edges by formulating a new proof of the removal lemma which does not use regularity.

Now to my question : I am interested in an algorithmic implementation of Jacob Fox's proof of the removal lemma - and in particular I am curious as to what running times can be achieved for such an implementation. The proof seems algorithmically implementable but as I said I did not find any mention of this and of what the running times would be.

I would appreciate any help I can get, thank you!